# How to handle "Current system mode is read-only" when using IoTDB?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I inserted data to Apache IoTDB, the server log show that "Current system mode is read-only". And I found no data was inserted successfully, how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some conditions when the system will automatically switch into read-only mode, e.g. when the disk is full or when the system encounters some kind of internal inconsistency.

In this case, you should first check if the node(s) are healthy (e.g. ressources, disk, ...) and if so, you can try to set the system back to writable state (http://iotdb.apache.org/UserGuide/V0.12.x/IoTDB-SQL-Language/Maintenance-Command.html#set-ststem-to-readonly-writable) by using

```
SET SYSTEM TO WRITABLE
```

via CLI.

Another cause could be that the system was set manually to read-only state, in this case you can proceed as stated above (this can be done via `SET SYSTEM TO READONLY`).